# How to change an image color with hover effect (CSS)?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, effect

I'm trying to set a hover effect over an image, so that it changes color when the mouse is over it. That's my html:

```
  <div class="col s4">
  <ul id="social">
  <li id="fb"></li>
  <li id="tw"></li>
  <li id="em"></li>
  <li id="fa"></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

And that's my CSS:

```
ul#social li#fb {
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    background-image:url(../img/social/Facebook-icon-(1).png);
}

ul#social li#fb:hover{
    background-image:url(../img/social/Facebook-icon.png);
}

[...]
```

The first background-image is in black and white , the second is in color . Unfortunately , however , my code does not work: it does not display the image in black and white. If imposed as background-image the color image I can see it properly, but the hover effect will not work anyway.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: you can try to make one image that has the two states in in, displaying the first normal en changing the background-position on :hover

Comment: i geuss that the () in your image name are the reason for this to happen

Comment: working http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/b320darL/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in `:hover`, so it's probably in your image path.

I pasted your code in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkf9n4ky/), only changing background-image to background-color and you can see that it changes from red to green when your mouse is over it.